# Map two lists (one of which is a list of lists) into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 lists:

```
List_1: [a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,a,a]
```

and a corresponding list `List_2: [{1,2,3},{5,6,9},{10},{11},{27,18,29},{1,2,3},{7,10},{34},{83},{60}]` which is a list of sets for each of the elements in the List_1.

I need a dictionary keyed by the unique elements in `list_1` and valued by their corresponding (concatenated) lists from `list_2`. So for example, the output I'd be looking for here would be:

```
Dict = {a:[1,2,3,5,6,9,10,83,60], b:[11,27,18,29], c:[1,2,3,7,10,34]}
```

My first instinct was `dict(zip(list_1,list_2))` which obviously hasn't worked...

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: `List_2` is actually a list of sets, not a _list of lists_ as you write

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry been looking at this code for a while...will amend now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a']
list_2 = [{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 9}, {10}, {11}, {27, 18, 29}, {1, 2, 3}, {7, 10}, {34}, {83}, {60}]

result = defaultdict(list)
for e1, e2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    result[e1].extend(e2)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 10, 83, 60], 'b': [11, 18, 27, 29], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 10, 7, 34]})
```

If you really need a dictionary, just do `dict(result)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
li_1 = ["a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a"]
li_2 = [{1,2,3},{5,6,9},{10},{11},{27,18,29},{1,2,3},{7,10},{34},{83},{60}]

di = { }
for ndx,i in enumerate(li_1):
    if i in di:
        di[i].extend(list(li_2[ndx]))
    else:
        di[i] = list(li_2[ndx])

print(di)
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 10, 83, 60], 'b': [11, 18, 27, 29], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 10, 7, 34]}
```

To reduce the number of lines, you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from python [collection module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html). Using this we can avoid `if` clause in the for loop.

```
from collections import defaultdict

li_1 = ["a","a","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a"]
li_2 = [{1,2,3},{5,6,9},{10},{11},{27,18,29},{1,2,3},{7,10},{34},{83},{60}]

di = defaultdict(list)
for ndx,i in enumerate(li_1):
    di[i].extend(li_2[ndx])

print(dict(di))
```

> My first instinct was dict(zip(list_1,list_2)) which obviously hasn't worked

`dict(zip(list_1,list_2))` discards all but the last set associated with a key. See the below code:

```
di = defaultdict(list)
for i,j in zip(li_1, li_2):
    di[i].extend(j)

print(dict(di))
```

Comment: Your last (correct) example is distinctly different from `dict(zip(list_1, list2))`, which effectively discards all but the last set associated with a key.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Do you mean first two examples doesn't work?

Comment: The first two should be fine; I was just quibbling over your original statement that `dict(zip(...))` should work, since you then proceeded to use `zip` in a different context.

Answer (score 0):

Use defaultdict from collections

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> my_dict = defaultdict(set)
>>> for k, v in zip(a, b):
...     my_dict[k] = my_dict[k].union(v)
... 
>>> dict(my_dict)
{'a': {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 83, 60}, 'b': {27, 18, 11, 29}, 'c': {1, 2, 3, 34, 7, 10}}
```